# Unique constraint exception in Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, session

I am using one oracle db with two copies of same application one is uploaded to server and one through local host through remote connection.problem is in primary key constraint on inserting entries in db table by both application.Suppose there is 5 entries in db table with last entry having primary key value 5,currently both the applications having last value 5 in session,now suppose one application inserts a new row it will increment primary key to 6 and inserts it successfully now if second application wants to insert a row in same table it will try to insert with primary key 6 because in its session last value was 5,but in the db there is already a row with primary key 6(inserted by first app) there it gives Unique constraint exception.

can anyone suggest how to take current value of primary key from DB not from session...??? Thanks in Advance..

Comment: How are your IDs generated? Show us your code.

Comment: Using Hbm file its auto generated i.e. <generator class="increment" />

Comment: You chose, among the many generators, the one that is explicitely documented as not usable in a cluster: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e2551. Use a sequence, or an identity, or a table-based generator.

Comment: So is this working for same DB with multiple web application right ??

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "this". A sequence-based generator, or an identity generator, or a table-based generator will indeed work even if multiple app instances access the same DB